# Livereload and Chrome. Force hard reload

Tags: google-chrome, livereload

I've started using LiveReload with its Chrome extension and that's greatly improved my workflow. 
But one thing I noticed: sometimes Chrome still keeps loading cached version where my recent changes aren't reflected.

How can I force it to always dump the cache and do 'hard reload'?

App runs on Visual Studio Web Development Server (I don't know if that matters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok... It seems you can click on the cog at the right bottom of dev-tools panel and disable caching...

Answer (score 1):

This helped me with development [chrome dns cache](http://chrome://net-internals/#dns) .

Also for testing purpose try to preview page in chrome incognito (ctrl + shift +n )

Other method would be to access inspector chrome tool and in the Application tab click on 'Clear site data'